# How do I display certain widgets based on a ListView selection in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart

I have ListView that displays "Today", "This Week" and "Detailed". Beneath that is a ListView of a custom designed Widget that just displays the temperature, day/hour, and a weather icon. What I am trying to do is show the hourly forecast when "Today" is selected and by default, and the daily forecast when "This Week" is selected. I've seemed to hit somewhat of a wall in this the past couple of days. I'm getting the feeling that I can't change around the contents of that list view from another list view.

I've tried to set it so that when "This Week" is clicked, the List of hourly info gets deleted and the List of daily info is populated but that doesn't work and wouldn't be a good solution. I want to put a method into the onTap on each heading, like the "Detailed" one which simply takes me to a new screen.

Here is the row of forecast info code, and it may have gotten a bit spaghetti like this afternoon so apologies for that :D I've put all of the info I want to display in it for now just for testing purposes.

```
                      Container(
                        height: 150,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 30),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFF2F3148),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemCount: 1,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: [
                                  hourlyWeather[0],
                                  hourlyWeather[1],
                                  hourlyWeather[2],
                                  hourlyWeather[3],
                                  hourlyWeather[4],
                                  hourlyWeather[5],
                                  hourlyWeather[6],
                                  hourlyWeather[7],
                                  hourlyWeather[8],
                                  hourlyWeather[9],
                                  hourlyWeather[10],
                                  hourlyWeather[11],
                                  dailyWeather[0],
                                  dailyWeather[1],
                                  dailyWeather[2],
                                  dailyWeather[3],
                                  dailyWeather[4],
                                  dailyWeather[5],
                                  dailyWeather[6],
                                ],
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
```

Here is the code above it that I want to use to control what is displayed in the previous code:

```
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: weatherInfo.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return GestureDetector(

                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedIndex = index;

                                      //Today
                                      if (selectedIndex == index &&
                                          weatherInfo[selectedIndex] ==
                                              "Today") {
                                        print("Test Today");
                                      }

                                      //This Week
                                      if (selectedIndex == index &&
                                          weatherInfo[selectedIndex] ==
                                              "This Week") {
                                        print("Test");
                                      }

                                      //Detail
                                      if (selectedIndex ==
                                              index && //GOING TO DETAIL SCREEN
                                          weatherInfo[selectedIndex] ==
                                              "Detailed") {
                                        toDetailScreen();
                                        //Sets the Today text to be underlined
                                        selectedIndex = 0;
                                      } //End of Detail IF statement

                                    });
                                  },
```

I'd really appreciate any advice you guys have to point me in the right direction, it's a really pretty little app and I'd love to get it published looking like this, rather than adding a whole other Daily forecast bit onto the screen to display all the info at the same time.

I'd be happy to clarify more or add some code if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you would want to work with Tabs instead of a list view for the top level selection choices. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

Another option would be to have the ListView of weather data be built from a stream of data using a StreamBuilder and have the buttons push data to the stream.